# how to set format date in script google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatdatetime

i got a spreadsheet with automatical (trigger) sending mail each day by pdf with this code :

```
function sendmail1() {

  var email = "xxx@xxx.fr"; 
  var feuille = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sujet = "Rapport journalier"; 
  var corpsDuMessage = "<p>Bonjour,</p>Ci-joint rapport journalier d'hier.<p>Bonne journée.</p>";
  var contenant = DriveApp.getFileById(feuille.getId()).getAs("application/pdf");
  
  contenant.setName(feuille.getName() + ".pdf");
  
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, sujet, corpsDuMessage, {
      htmlBody: corpsDuMessage,
      attachments:[contenant]     
    });  
}
```

i would like to set "sujet" adding a date in the cell A1.
how ?
and how to set the format ? don't want :
Tue Sep 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)
i would like to have format YYYY-MM-DD
2020-09-01

thank your for your help

code2

```
function sendmail1() {

  var email = "xxx@xxx.fr"; 
  var feuille = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sujet = "Rapport journalier"; 
  var corpsDuMessage = "<p>Bonjour,</p>Ci-joint rapport journalier d'hier.<p>Bonne journée.</p>";
  var contenant = DriveApp.getFileById(feuille.getId()).getAs("application/pdf");
  
  contenant.setName(feuille.getName() + ".pdf");
  
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(
  email,
  sujet +
    Utilities.formatDate(
      feuille
        .getSheetByName('Sheet1')
        .getRange('A1')
        .getValue(),
      feuille.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),
      'yyyy-MM-dd'
    ),
  corpsDuMessage,
  {/*....*/}
);
}
```

Comment: You should have used proper tags for the question to have reached the intended audience.

Comment: sorry bad english and lost in script

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)):

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(
  email,
  sujet +
    Utilities.formatDate(
      feuille
        .getSheetByName('Sheet1')
        .getRange('A1')
        .getValue(),
      feuille.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),
      'yyyy-MM-dd'
    ),
  corpsDuMessage,
  {/*....*/}
);
```

Comment: thank you. now wih the whole code edit code2 in my question, i got an error : "TypeError : Cannot read property "getRange' of null (ligne 18, fichier 'Code'')

Comment: @MaisonGuéret1880 Did you provide the correct sheet name? It's  `Sheet1` in my example.

Comment: ... sure ... You are right i didn't ... Now it's ok. Thank you. [solved]